# Нужна ли запятая перед кавычками?

Tags: цитирование

Президент России Владимир Путин заявил сегодня после переговоров с президентом Франции Франсуа Олландом в аэропорту «Внуково», что «как известно, Россия территориальную целостность Украины поддерживает».

В интервью он добавил, что «создавая что-то новое, необязательно разрушать старое».

Нужна ли запятая после *что*?

Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента, выделяется кавычками (но начинается со строчной буквы), а знаки препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим строем предложения: 
Мысль Л.Н. Толстого «время есть отношение движения своей жизни к движению других существ», высказанная в его дневниках, имеет философское содержание.

5 декабря глава Чечни Рамзан Кадыров опубликовал в Instagram'e запись о том, что родители должны отвечать за поступки своих сыновей и дочерей, и если "боевик совершит убийство, его семья будет немедленно выдворена из Чечни без права возвращения, а дом снесен".

Однако перед открывающими кавычками запятая не опускается: Вспомните, «как хороши, как свежи были розы».

Судя по этой рекомендации, запятая нужна.

Comment: doom, хотел бы посоветовать не заниматься "награждением" других участников. Тем самым вы лишаете этих очков себя (этот механизм здесь вообще очень плохо продуман), а они вам куда нужнее, если собираетесь задержаться на ресурсе.

Если вы хотите высказать свое отношение, вполне достаточно просто поставить "лайк"/"дислайк" ответу.

Comment: Запятая не ставится,если цитата выступает как дополнение или как часть придаточного предложения:Пастернак писал, что ***«изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается всего непосредственнее».***  

Comment: >Запятая не ставится,если цитата выступает как дополнение или как часть придаточного   
  
О какой запятой речь? В вашем примере и обособления-то нет, какая еще запятая?

Отсюда, что ли?
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_76  
  
Это не совсем не то, о чем мы разговариваем. 
Здесь речь о знаках, присоединяющих цитату к остальной части текста, а автор вопроса спрашивает о запятой, которая ставится по совершенно другим мотивам: как способ обособления оборота. Этот оборот у него в примере присутствует в самой цитате.

Comment: doom, Ваши примеры - на разные случаи. Пример от Кадырова вообще "страдает" пунктуацией. Там и запятая перед И в высшей степени сомнительна. А вот перед "если" она как раз была бы понятна, если бы не кавычки. Вопрос, как я понимаю, в том, нужна ли она при наличии этих кавычек.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, нужна, чтобы сохранить структуру предложения

Answer (score 1):

Запятая перед кавычками тут невозможна. Она относится к части предложения в кавычках и по логике должна быть именно там поставлена. Иначе первая кавычка окажется внутри обособляемой части. И обратно, открывающая кавычка окажется внутри обособляемой части. 
Её бы, эту запятую, внутри кавычек поставить, но тогда она следовала бы сразу за открывающей кавычкой, что еще больший нонсенс.

Ничего страшного, иногда эта запятая опускается на встрече с другими знаками препинания. 
*NN cказал: "как известно, ..."* Не будете требовать запятую пред кавычками?
А ведь это почти тот же случай: вводное в начале новой фразы. Разница разве лишь в том, что в прямой речи эта фраза начинается с заглавной буквы...

(+)---------- 8.12.2014

> Судя по этой рекомендации, запятая нужна.

В рекомендации идет речь о запятой, ставящейся по совершенно другим мотивам. Та запятая присоединяет цитату как подчиненное предложение, - у вас аналог этой запятой стоит перед "что", а не пред кавычками. Про способы оформления обособленного оборота внутри кавычек в рекомендации ничего не говорится.

(+)---------- 12.12.2014 
Чем дальше в лес, тем толще партизаны...
Мне еще раз возразили.
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5465
Я бы поверил, но фраза "не видим разницы" лишила всякого доверия к ответу. 
Разница-то видна невооруженным глазом. 
Т.е. меня не убедили "ни разу", но сил спорить больше нет. Может, со временем найдется пример более убедительный.

Comment: @behemothus,а что дают очки? И еще: как вам удается узнать, кто кого каким количеством очков наградил?

Comment: Я только про себя могу сказать. Все есть в логах. 
"Наградные очки" - это обычная репутация, которой можно "поделиться" с ближним. Что касается "что дают", вы, наверное, давно это знаете.

http://russ.hashcode.ru/faq/#heading13

Цифры там не соответствуют реально используемым, но суть понятна.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что запятая здесь не нужна: В интервью он добавил, что «создавая что-то новое, необязательно разрушать старое». Но: Вспомните, «как хороши, как свежи были розы».

В этих предложениях применяются разные способы цитирования. В первом случае мы от прямой речи переходим к косвенной, используя форму придаточного изъяснительного предложения: после союза "что" следует дословное воспроизведение прямой речи с **первого слова**, поэтому нет запятой.

Во втором случае прямая речь встраивается в предложение. Это означает, что только наличие кавычек говорит нам о том, что это передача дословного высказывания. Знаки препинания обозначают структуру сложноподчиненного предложения с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая ставится перед  союзом КАК.